# Can You Add a Multiple of a Matrix Row to itself?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I apologize in advance, as it seems this might be one of those questions that is so mind-boggling obvious to those who know the answer that most don't even think to treat upon it. I've searched up and down for information on matrice elementary row operations, but none of them have thought to explicitly treat upon the addition of a multiple of a matrix row to itself.

All of them say that it is possible to add a multiple of a matrix row to another row, but does adding a multiple of a matrix row to itself present a special case? Is it legal? It's a relatively straightforward question, I suppose, but I haven't been able to find confirmation one way or another on the topic. :(

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I suppose you intend to ask this question in the context of diagonalization of a matrix, as usually, you cannot fiddle with a matrix without changing the way it acts on a vector. The addition of a multiple (say $n$) of a matrix row to itself corresponds to a multplication of that row by $n+1$, which corresponds to multiplying one equation in a linear system of equations by a number. This is a perfecly legal operation.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it is possible" to add a multiple of a matrix row to another row?  Of course it's possible, who's going to stop us?  We'll get a new matrix if we do that.

Comment: How is this different from multiplying that row by a constant ($1$ more than the multiple you're thinking of)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, in the context of Gaussian elimination (which is where one allows adding multiples of one row to another row) there is an exception for addition to the same row; instead it is allowed to multiply a row by a **nonzero** constant. There is a good reason for the exception: if one were to allow adding a multiple of the row to itself, one could take the multiple to be $-1$ times the row, and the result would simply replace the rows by zero. That is not allowed, as it is a patently non-reversible operation; doing so will in general enlarge the solution set of the system under consideration. One could allow adding a multiple by any factor $\alpha\neq-1$, but that is already covered under the rule allowing multiplication by a nonzero constant (it has the same effect as multiplication by $1+\alpha$). Excluding $0$ as a multiplication factor is easier to state and to understand then excluding $-1$ as factor when adding a multiple, but only if the destination is the row itself.

Comment: You could in principle just _always_ exclude the factor $-1$: it's still possible to achieve subtraction of row $A$ from row $B$ by first setting $B ← B + A$ and then $B ← B - 2\cdot A$. But I agree that the standard rules are more elegant.

Comment: are you allowed to multiply two rows and add them to a different row?

for instance; $R_4 \to R_4 + R_3 \cdot R_2$?

Comment: @Jneven no that is not allowed, but what does it even mean? There is no vector-valued product of vectors (except the cross-product in dimension $3$) that could be used here.

Comment: example: Given a matrix, as $a\neq b \neq c, \ d \neq e \neq f$ - all are scalars $ \in \mathbb{R}$. Let:
$A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 1\\
a & b & c\\
d & e & f\\
ad & be & cf
\end{array}\right)$


Find the rank of the matrix

Comment: That rank (which of course cannot be $4$) is generically $3$, certainly so when the first three rows are linearly independent. It is still generically $3$ when the first  three rows are linearly dependent. In fact if instead of what you wrote you meant $a,b,c$ are all three distinct, one can prove the rank is _always_ $3$ (assume the second row is a linear combination of the first two, then the determinant on rows $1,2,4$ reduces to the Vandermonde determinant for $a,b,c$, which is nonzero by assumption). Your assumption does not exclude $(a,b,c)=(d,e,f)=(1,0,1)$, for which the rank is $2$.

Comment: @Jneven But while that it a nice exercise, it has nothing to do with the OP question.

Comment: I agree! therefore I asked :)

Answer (score 3):

Just left-multiply by

$$\mathrm I + \alpha \, \mathrm e_i \mathrm e_i^{\top}$$

to multiply the $i$-th row by $1+\alpha$.

Comment: Rodrigo's formula synthesizes  4 steps: 1. To obtain row from matrix $A$ we do operation: ${e_i}^TA$ . 2 To multiple this row by $\alpha\ $:  $\alpha{e_i}^TA$ 3. To transform row into matrix where a obtained row be i-th row , and  rest are zero rows: ${e_i}{\alpha}{e_i}^TA$  4. To obtain a sum we do: ${e_i}{\alpha}{e_i}^TA +A$.

Comment: What does $e_i$ denote here?

Comment: @loa_in_ $e_i$ typically denotes a column vector of all zeros with a single $1$ in the $i$th spot.

Answer (score 3):

Each step of the Gauss elimination can be modeled by mulitplying the matrix with a so called elementary matrix, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix).

> All of them say that it is possible to add a multiple of a matrix row
>   to another row, but does adding a multiple of a matrix row to itself
>   present a special case? Is it legal?

Sure it is legal, adding the $i$-th row of $A$ to row $i$ using the above definition would be the operation
$$
L_{i,i}(1) A
$$
with
$$
L_{i,i}(1) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & & & & & & & \\ & \ddots & & & & & & \\ & & 2 & & & & & \\ & & & \ddots & & & & \\ & &  & & 1 & & \\ & & & & & & \ddots & \\ & & & & & & & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$
Note that this elementary matrix is the same as $D_i(2)$, scalar multiplying a row by $2$.